# how to get Outlook Express to continue after failing to read a newsgroup message

Tags: newsgroup, outlook

I use outlook express as a newsreader.  Sometimes I want to get the entire server holdings of a particular newsgroup.  Trouble is, OE seems to snag when it was able to read a message headr but for some reason it can't retrieve the body.  It snags with

```
Outlook Express could not download the requested message. It is likely that the message
was removed or expired from the server.  Subject 'Simple security??', Account:
'news.nevrona.com', Server: 'news.nevrona.com', Protocol: NNTP, Port: 119, Secure(SSL):
No, Error Number: 0x800C006F
```

and the only option you have is to stop.  Any messages after that one you can't retrieve.

Has anybody seen this problem?  Or can suggest a better newsreader? (tried Gravity, found it hard to use.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to:

- download all the headers from the server
- try to download all the messages
- note which note which message gives the error
- find the header corresponding to the message
- delete it from OE
- try to download all the messages again
- repeat with the next header that snags until finished.

When I did this there were only a few messages that needed to have their headers deleted before I was able to get the whole server contents.